# Calculate An Objects Local Axes DirectX 11

Tags: c++, object, directx-11

I think this is a very easy question but I can't seem to grasp the idea. I have a bounding box around a model which is rotated. Now to perform an OBB collision check I need the boxes "local axes". I've no idea how to work this out, is it simply a rotation * translation matrix?

Thank you,

Comment: Look at the code in ``DirectXCollision.h`` and ``DirectXCollision.inl`` for the ``BoundingOrientedBox`` class.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the reply! I have checked it and it didn't shed too much light on it unfortunately as it doesn't use the same three variables that I've read about on everything else :|

Thank you!